# Add to a list that is in a SortedList

Tags: c#, .net, list, sortedlist

I'm trying to add objects to a list that is inside a "sorted list"

Example:
public SortedList<string,List<ToolCommandDiscoveryHelper.DiscoveredTool>> categories { get; set; }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
please provide the code that you have tried already, 
the expected behaviour and the actual results, so we can see what is wrong

Comment: categories[yourKey].YourList.Add(obj)

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer:
ex:

```
var sortedTools = new SortedTools();

sortedTools.categories[*keyvalue*].Add(*object*);
```